# How to change y-axis in 'plotyy' to natural log scale in matlab

Tags: matlab, plot

Unless otherwise stated "log" will refer to natural log.

I'm using `plotyy` in matlab to plot 2 sets of data. The first set is (x,Q), where Q = -ln(y). Note that "ln" here is NOT a function call...it is the expression for the natural log. The second set is (x,q), where `q = 1/exp(Q)`. I want the y-axis of the second set to be presented on a log scale. My function call is

```
plotyy(x,Q,x,q,'plot','semilogy')
```

Since `semilogy` is a base 10, the lines do not overlap. How do I get the y-axis of the second set to be presented on a log scale?

I can't touch `Q` and it is to remain plotted on a linear scale. Changing that is not an option. In the end the plots should be identical where the only thing that changes is the scale on the second y-axis. I will also note that y covers both positive and negative numbers.

Comment: Matlab doesn't have `ln`. You mean `log`, right?

Comment: Sorry, that's the actual expression of the data...not a program call. I'll edit that to prevent further confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matlab doesn't offer natural `log` as scaling of axes. But since your goal is to overlap the left and the right side of the axes, you can simply choose the limits on the right side to be equivalent with the ones on the left:

```
ha = plotyy(x,log(y),x,y,'plot','semilogy'); % handles of both axes
leftlim = ylim(ha(1)); % reading ylim of the left side
ylim(ha(2), [exp(leftlim(1)), exp(leftlim(2))]) % changing ylim of the right side
```

Comment: Magnificent! That was easier that I expected.